# How to sort column of means with Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am finding mean values by using `groupBy` and `mean` functions, like this.

```
x.groupBy("Col1", "Col2" "Col3").mean("Col4")
```

However, I want to later also sort the column with means. How can I do that? I know that we can can use the `orderBy` function to sort a column, but that can be used only with column with names, while we don't have any name for the column with means.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
x.groupBy("Col1", "Col2" "Col3").mean("Col4").alias("Mean").orderBy("Mean")
```

I also tried `as` instead of `alias`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Why wouldn't you know the column name?

Comment: Because mean would create a new column. Is there a way to find the name in that case?

Comment: If I understood well, you want to alias the name so it can be known in the runtime? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alias your column with `as`.

So the name would be known in the runtime !

`x.groupBy("Col1", "Col2" "Col3").agg(mean("Col4").as("CustomName"))`

Comment: So it has to be called with agg, I see.

Comment: Exactly, this way you can even have several aggregations !